# Java / JSP / Sessions

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have implemented a `SessionListener` to count sessions on my web app. I have `setMaxInterval(60)` and my problem is the following: if the session expires the session counter is set to 0 and if i start to navigate on the web page again, the session counter is not incremented. Why not?

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

static int counter = 0;

public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent e)
{
    HttpSession s = e.getSession();

    s.setMaxInactiveInterval(60);

    counter++;

    synchronized(s.getServletContext())
    {
        s.getServletContext().setAttribute("allConnections", counter);

    }
}

public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent e)
{
    HttpSession s = e.getSession();

    counter--;

    synchronized(s.getServletContext())
    {
        s.getServletContext().setAttribute("allConnections", counter);
    }


}
```

Then, each JSP display the counter variable on the frontend by `application.getAttribute("allConnections")`

Comment: Showing snippets from your code would greatly help answering more accurately.

Comment: Your original code worked for me. I just added debug lines to print to console. I printed the value of the counter in the  two methods. I also changed the inactive interval to 6 seconds. That way you can  just watch the console and see the counter go up and down quickly. I used three different browsers(IE, Chrome, and Firefox) on my desktop. Your code is ok.

Comment: I tested your code another way with a single browser. It works fine. I made a shortcut to the JSP on my desktop.  I  browsed to the page and then quickly shutdown the browser. I did the same thing over and over.

Comment: It is weird, now it displays null value instead of 0 or 1...

Comment: In the JSP, you should be using :  Session count is ${allConnections}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the counter variable in an object that's session-specific (you're storing it in the session object as an attribute or something similar)

Your solutions (you choose):
- Put the counter in the Application context/scope (or in a singleton object that's on that scope)
- Make the counter variable static (if it is in your listener)

**EDIT after question update**
The session attribute is being set once, when the session is created. This means that only the initial value (the one applicable when the session was created) will ever be shown for any given session.

The value must be read on each request that renders the page displaying the counter. You have a few options for this:

- The JSP/servlet can read the value directly, if you can provide a static getter in the `SessionListener` class
- Better: you could add a filter that sets the updated counter as an attribute in the request scope. You'd just have to make sure that the filter executes on each request (jsp, servlet, etc) that displays the counter.

Comment: I have provided the requested sample.

Comment: Unfortunately, the attribute is stored in the context scope. I really do not know what is going wrong.

Comment: Updated the answer. Suggest a filter or reading the value each time before displaying it.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still confused. I though `getServletContext().setAttribute()` will set a context attribute, which is being refreshed for all sessions concurrently.

Comment: Not in this case: SessionListener is a session listener, of which the method that you rely on gets called ONLY ONCE, when the session is created. That ``setAttribute`` method is invoked only when ``sessionCreated`` is run, leaving the value to never get updated afterwards. Newer sessions (you could try this with different browsers) will see the updated value, but not the same session on different requests/refreshes.

Comment: So basically, my initial session has never got killed?

Comment: That isn't the case. Even if your session gets killed, the counter state will survive as it is stored in a static field that will outlive many sessions. It is just that for any single session, your code displays only the value it found when that particular session was created, never refreshing it as pages are reloaded.

Comment: His code works fine. I tested it. See my comment at top.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a JSP may or may not create a session depending on the value of this directive:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```